# Is it possible to create a Facebook app page without uploading an app?

Tags: categories, facebook-page

I am working on making a game that we plan to upload to Facebook in just under 3 months.  However, we would like to make a Facebook page to try to get publicity before we upload it.  I'm not sure if we should categorize it as a Games/Toys page or an App Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the app page just lets you have the codes for the API. You can change the catagory later.

Comment: So I don't have to upload an app.  Thanks!

Comment: Did I do that?  I'm new to Stack Overflow.